# JS round to 2 decimal places

Tags: javascript, decimal

I am trying to limit the returned number to be only 2 decimal places but this code isn't working for me;

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Result is: " + x * 1.09; value = valToRound.toFixed(2);
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `valToRound`? What's that?

Comment: Um, you are not assigning the rounded number to the innerHTML?

Answer (score 13):

Typing in the JS Browser console

```
  x = 2.71828
  x.toFixed(2)
  "2.72"
```

it is clear that `.toFixed(2)` works

What you did wrong was rounding *after* printing the answer, and not using the correct variables.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Result is: " + x * 1.09; value = valToRound.toFixed(2);
```

It is also a good idea to get in the habit of converting strings to numbers with `parseFloat()`.  In JS, '2'*'2' is '4' but '2'+'2' is '22', unless you first convert to number.

If you do it this way it will work:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mySelect").value);
  var valToRound = x * 1.09;
  var value = valToRound.toFixed(2);
  document.getElementByID("demo").innerHTML = "Result is: " + value;
}
```