# Javascript Function Returning NaN

Tags: javascript

I'm making a calculator that will take inputs from a survey form and then push results to an object so I can display it on other parts of the site and use chart.js

However, I can't get the first calculation to work. My first function is to calculate the 30% saving of monthly gas spend (gas) and to subtract the saving from a monthly payment (price). I'm getting NaN in the console when the site loads even before clicking the button which has the eventlistener assigned to it.

Where am I going wrong?

P.S I haven't made the form responsive yet so it will need to be viewed in a full browser.

```js
const calculate = document.getElementById('one');

calculate.addEventListener('click', calc());

function calc() {
    let gas = parseInt(document.getElementById('gas').value);
    let price = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);
    let gasSaving;
    let result;
    gasSaving = gas * 0.3;
    result = price - gasSaving;
    console.log(result);
}
```

```css
/* Survery Section Start */

.survery {
    background-color: #1b262c;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.survery-h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

input {
    text-indent: 10px;
}

.survery-questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.home-name-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.home-phone-footer {
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.home-email-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.btn-calc {
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    width: 15rem;
    background-color: #168ecf;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #eee;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Survery Start -->
   <section class="survery">
       <div class="survery-title">
           <h1 class="survery-h1">Scrappage Payment Survey</h1>
       </div>
        <form action="">
        <div class="survery-questions">
                <div class="name-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Gas Supplier" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Gas Meter Serial No." class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="email-form">
                    <input  placeholder="Monthly Gas Spend" class="home-email-footer" id="gas" required>
                </div>

                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="System Monthly Payment" class="home-phone-footer" id="price" required>
                </div>

                <div class="name-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number Of Bathrooms" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number Of Radiators" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>

                <div class="name-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="System Size Required (Kw)" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number Of Residents" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>
                <div class="thebutton">
                    <button class="btn-calc" id="one">Calculate</button>
                
                </form>

            </div>
       </div>
   </section>
 <!-- Survery End-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you shouldn't call the function calc while adding the eventListener:`calculate.addEventListener('click', calc);`

Comment: Ok, I've made the changes but my function doesn't work at all. I'm not sure why

Comment: @Anon2945 By removing the parentheses you register the function as event handler. You now have to click the calculate button to run your function.

Answer (score 4):

> calculate.addEventListener('click', calc());

to

> calculate.addEventListener('click', calc);

the `calc()` with parentheses will execute the function directly, whilst without it will only be called upon.

Also, you should add an event prevent default to not having the page refreshed.

```
const calculate = document.getElementById('one');

calculate.addEventListener('click', calc);

function calc(event) {

    // Prevent page refresh.
    event.preventDefault();

    let gas = parseInt(document.getElementById('gas').value);
    let price = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);
    let gasSaving;
    let result;
    gasSaving = gas * 0.3;
    result = price - gasSaving;
    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Why does the page refresh in this example? Examples I've seen of simple calculators on youtube don't add the even.preventDefault(); Also, how can I round the result to 2 decimal places? Thanks

Comment: @Anon2945 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300649/js-round-to-2-decimal-places

Comment: @Anon2945 it refreshes per default since you have a button inside an `<form>` element.

Comment: Ahhh, makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You can omit `event.preventDefault()` if you set the `<button type="button"` otherwise it defaults to a `type="submit"`. When using "button": *"The button has no default behavior, and does nothing when pressed by default. It can have client-side scripts listen to the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur."* [MDN `<button>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes)

Comment: I've added. toFixed(2) so I can get my result to 2 decimal places, but the input fields don't pick up the decimal places. So for example if I enter 35.86 for price, it will do the calulation based on 35 and not 35.86

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve the issue: Please check

```js
const calculate = document.getElementById('one');

calculate.addEventListener('click', calc);

function calc() {
    let gas = parseInt(document.getElementById('gas').value);
    let price = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);
    let gasSaving;
    let result;
    gasSaving = gas * 0.3;
    result = price - gasSaving;
    console.log(result);
}
```

```css
/* Survery Section Start */

.survery {
    background-color: #1b262c;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.survery-h1 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5rem;
}

input {
    text-indent: 10px;
}

.survery-questions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.home-name-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

.home-phone-footer {
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}

.home-email-footer {
    width: 600px;
    height: 45px;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    margin-left: 90px;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

#input {
    background: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.btn-calc {
    padding: 1rem 2.5rem;
    width: 15rem;
    background-color: #168ecf;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #eee;
    transition: all .5s;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Survery Start -->
   <section class="survery">
       <div class="survery-title">
           <h1 class="survery-h1">Scrappage Payment Survey</h1>
       </div>
        <form action="">
        <div class="survery-questions">
                <div class="name-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Gas Supplier" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Gas Meter Serial No." class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>
                
                <div class="email-form">
                    <input  placeholder="Monthly Gas Spend" class="home-email-footer" id="gas" required>
                </div>

                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="System Monthly Payment" class="home-phone-footer" id="price" required>
                </div>

                <div class="name-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number Of Bathrooms" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number Of Radiators" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>

                <div class="name-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="System Size Required (Kw)" class="home-name-footer" id="input" required>
                
                </div>
                
                <div class="phone-form">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Number Of Residents" class="home-phone-footer" id="input" required>
                </div>
                <div class="thebutton">
                    <button class="btn-calc" id="one">Calculate</button>
                
                </form>

            </div>
       </div>
   </section>
 <!-- Survery End-->
</body>
</html>
```

Hope, it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Step #1
I added jquery reference in the head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Step #2
I added onclick event to call calc() function
Calculate
Step #3
I added this script now it's working fine

function calc() {
    debugger
    let gas = parseInt(document.getElementById('gas').value);
    let price = parseInt(document.getElementById('price').value);
    let gasSaving;
    let result;
    gasSaving = gas * 0.3;
    result = price - gasSaving;
    console.log(result);
}

What I understand your are not properly calling the event that's why NAN(Not a Number) is appearing in the console and the second thing you asked in the comment about round off it is very simple
https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/jsref_round.asp
please check this link it will help you